# How can I find the closest parent component?

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, extjs4

An ExtJS component (let it be component A) is rendered to some DOM element. This DOM element itself later is used like contentEl for some other EXtJS component (componentB).

What is the simplest way to find out that componentA is rendered for some element which is, in turn, used by some componentB. To put it simple, is there something like jquery's closest, but as we have components instead of DOM elements?

**UPD:** I know about so called `ComponentQuery` language and the `up` method, I have a strong feeling that solution is somewhere close to, but I just can't figure out, how exactly it can be done. The problem with 'up' method is, as far as I can understand, it actually test chain of directly declared ancestors. By "directly directed" I mean each new component has been inserted directly as child to its parent. In my case, this chain is broken.

Comment: Did you check Ext.ComponentQuery? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: @amol, thank you, and yes, I'm actually supposing the answer is somewhere in the area of ComponentQuery, but can not figure out, how I can match parent containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you have to fall back to DomQuery and simply check if the DOM node contains a div with a classname that your suspected component is supposed to generate. It's a hack, but what you are doing looks also like a hack.

Maybe you can structure your things differently, so that the child components somehow register themselves with the parent. Hard to suggest much without knowing the particulars.

Comment: can you, please, describe me your idea more in detail. So, you suppose to find the DOM element and then some how find the associated component. First step is obvious to me, second - well, not so obvious. Off the top of my head, I can imagine following - we find DOM element, and get some data, which has been associated with this element somehow earlier. Using this data (in simplest form it can be just a component id), we find the appropriate component.

Comment: You simply need to find the root element of a component, get its ID and pass the ID to Ext.getCmp() to get the component.